# jQuery - choose date from slider select

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm beginner in jquery and i need to do something like shown in the link bellow.

http://hpics.li/514a251

I want to choose a date from a manual slider with tooltip.

Do you have any idea or example to that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this examples. The second one is fit your stuff.
[Exampl1](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html)
[Example2](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/working-with-dates)